# Check given web site is hosted or not using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I need to check if a URL (www.google.com / www.googlesss.com)exists.
we support various browsers (IE, Chrome, Firefox etc...) so the solution needs to be able to support all of those.

I.E

```
var backendUrl = "https://www.google.co.in";
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: backendUrl
}).done(function (result) {
   console.log("working");
}).fail(function () {
   alert("Sorry URL is not access able");
});
```

Output:

if backendUrl = "https://www.google.co.in"; then return working
if backendUrl = "https://www.yahoo.co.in"; then return working
if backendUrl = "https://www.googlessss.co.in"; then Sorry URL is not access able

Answer (score 1):

You can make `HEAD` request first to identify resource is able to comminicate with you without sending response data.

So you can detect is this url is valid with minimal amount of transfered data.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'HEAD',
    async: true,
    url: url,
}).then(function(message,text,jqXHR){
    //valid url
}, function() {
    //not valid url
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```js
var backendUrl = "https://www.google.co.in";
$.get(backendUrl).done(function () {
  // REACHABLE
}).fail(function () {
  // UNREACHABLE
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```